# Terminal exits after pressing <Enter> or <Tab>

Tags: 14.04, command-line

When I open terminal and press `Enter` or `Tab` multiple times, terminal exits i.e. when i type `ls` and press `Enter` or `cd` and press `Tab` all the terminal window get close. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

This behavior is usual if you have the line `set -e` in your `~/.bashrc` or any user/global configuration file of the shell that will be sourced when you start the shell. From `help set`:

```
-e  Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.
```

Run the following and try exactly what you were doing, you'll now get the normal behavior i.e. `bash_completion`:

```
set +e
```

To permanently fix this find where the `set -e` is set (should be in `~/.bashrc`) and either comment out that or set it as `set +e`.

Comment: I cannot find set -e in .bashrc.

Comment: Does setting `set +e` from terminal solve your problem?

Comment: No. The problem is still there.

Comment: Run `grep -r 'set -e' /home` and check the output.

Comment: The problem is also found in guest user, bt xterm is working properly. I upgraded Ubuntu, the problem isn't solved.

Comment: You have upgraded the distro version or packages?

Answer (score -1):

Its due to the change in permission settings of /tmp/ folder.

```
 chmod 1777 /tmp
```

Now the problem solved.